# Letter "p" in "consumption" word?

Tags: word-usage, word-form

The letter p "consumption" seems odd for me. Why does it not similar to "collect"+"ion"->"collection"? Is there any other similar noun?

Comment: This question might get better answers on [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com), or in the Oxford English Dictionary or another etymological dictionary.

Comment: In Oald's pronunciation the p is pronounced. http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/consumption?q=consumption

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both *consumption* and *collection* are derived from Latin past participle stems, *consumpt-*, *collect-*. The *-tion* suffix is an extension of the PaPpl *-txx* stem.

The difference in the two lies not in the *-tion* forms but in the underlying verbs. Our verb *consume* is derived from the indicative *consumo* rather than the PaPpl *consumpt-*, whereas our verb *collect* is derived from the past participle *collect-* rather than from the indicative *colligo*.

The Latin PaPpl is most often constructed by adding *-t-* to the stem, which in many contexts changes the final sound in the stem.  For instance:

- adding voiceless /t/ to a stem ending in voiced /g/ may result in /kt/ (spelled ‹ct›), with the /g/ "devoiced" to /k/. Compare *correct* and *corrigible*.
- adding /t/ to a stem ending in voiced /m/ may cause the sound to be "closed" with the voiceless stop /p/ pronounced at the same point, anticipating the voiceless stop /t/. Compare *redeem* and *redemption*.

Comment: @PHPst Sorry, Past Participle.

Comment: I think "Past Participle" is generally abbreviated as "p.p."   Is it your personal style of writing that?

Comment: @PHPst Yes - 'pp' might also be 'present participle' or 'preposition phrase', so I prefer something less ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

I have no sources and I'm horribly unqualified, but... to me this is reminiscent of the German "Fugenelement," which is a sound that is added based on phonetic context.  In other words, in this example the "p" kind of rolls off the tongue anyway, so it is added to transition from the bilabial nasal [m] to the denti-alveolar stop [t].  A similar phenomenon: have you ever heard people pronounce "hamster" as "hampster"?
Again, don't quote me on anything; this is just food for thought.